# Java Checking a player ID

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

currently working on a project and I have a player class where I have an ID that auto-increments every time an object is created and then all my objects are in an array list (PlayerList).I am trying to set the text of a label to the player name but it just skips the first player and then it won't loop back round I get a java runtime error.

This code loads all the players into the table:

```
public void initialize() {
    for (RadioButton button : radios) {
        button.setDisable(true);
        button.setOpacity(1);
    }
    loadPlayers();
    selectPlayer(0);
}

public void selectPlayer(int count){
    for(Player player : PlayerList) {
        if(player.getPlayerID() == count) {
            Player activePlayer = PlayerList.get(count);
            playerName.setVisible(true);
            String name = activePlayer.getName();
            playerName.setText(name);
            System.out.println(count);
            System.out.println(activePlayer);
        }
    }
}
```

From the code above I want to cycle through the list of players and pull the player from a count, I also have the code below to run on a button press, this code below adds to the count or resets the count.

```
if(count == PlayerList.size()){
        count = 0; //reset the count
    }else{
        count++;
        selectPlayer(count);
    }
```

When I'm running the code it always pulls the second player rather than the first one I'm not sure what is going wrong, any help will be very much appreciated.

**Updated**

```
if (count <= size) {
        Player activePlayer = PlayerList.get(count);
        playerName.setVisible(true);
        String name = activePlayer.getName();
        playerName.setText(name);
        System.out.println(count);
    }else if(count == size){
        count=0;
        selectPlayer(count);
    }
```

This is what I have got at the minute, it works but when I come to the last player I have to press the button twice to loop round to the start?

Comment: Not sure if you supplied enough info, but you are incrementing count before you call select player. In that case, count will never be zero.

Comment: try asking yourself, what would happen if count = 0.

Comment: I have updated the code for what I'm trying to do it works for the last two players just not for the first one, I want it so that when the scene loads it loads the first players name to the label, When the count ID is 1 it is pulling the player with a player id of 2

Comment: `selectPlayer` method is a bit odd btw: You search the list for players with an id of `count` and every time you encounter such a player you get the element at index `count` and do something with it. If player is always located at index `count`, why not immediately access this element? `if (count <= size) {Player activePlayer = PlayerList.get(count);...}`. If not, why access the element at this position instead of using the loop variable `player`. Also if the id is unique, why continue instead of using `break;`?

Comment: @fabian, thanks for your help, I have implemented the code, but when I come to the end of the loop I have to press the button twice to loop back around, is there a way around this? (Check the code above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's taking the second player cause you increment `count` first. The order is this:

```
selectPlayer(count);
count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you call the button press code the first time (assuming count == 0), it is falling into the "else" condition.  In the "else" block, the first thing you do is increment count (so now, count == 1). Your first player probably has ID=0, and your second player has ID=1.  To fix, switch the two lines in your else block so you select the player THEN increment count.